# Apple Script Editor to prevent QuickTime opening full screen

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I am trying to write an application using Script Editor to run when my Mac starts so that it plays a video and then closes the application. But I would prefer it not go into full screen mode, which is what it has been doing automatically. This is what I've tried so far (that is "fit to screen" on QuickTime)... any suggestions of what to do instead?

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "3" using command down
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use system events for this. From what you describe, this is a video over which you have some kind of control - you can perhaps edit it and resave?

I know that it used to be possible to set (or unset) the 'full screen' flag using AppleScript in Quicktime player. It might even be possible in the GUI.

Just checked: The property is called 'the presenting', so you'd do something like:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    tell (open file "xyz.m4v")
        set the presenting to false -- disable full screen playback
        play
    end tell
end tell
```

Quick tip: If you have Mac OS High Sierra or older, you can install QuickTime Player 7 from https://support.apple.com/kb/dl923. This will allow you to play dozens of exotic legacy multimedia file formats from the last century, and if you and enter a Pro key, you will be able to make simple edits to tracks and timeline, including setting the full screen flag. If you do this, then save the video (with a new name). Next time you open that video, it should no longer display in full screen.

Getting the player to quit after the video completes is more tricky, but maybe you have a solution for that. If not, you can save it as an AppleScript **application**, **set to stay open**, which polls the state of QuickTime Player playback once per second on idle (this is the maximum rate). When the movie is finished, the AppleScript can close QuickTime Player and quit. The full script would be something like this:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    tell (open file "Macintosh HD:Users:Laura:Movies:xyz.m4v")
        set the presenting to false -- disable full screen playback
        play
    end tell
end tell
on idle
    tell application "QuickTime Player"

        if document 1 exists then
            tell document 1
                if (not playing) and (current time > (duration - 1)) then
                    quit
                    tell me to quit -- quit the AppleScript itself
                end if
            end tell
        else -- no movie open, perhaps it failed, or got moved
            tell me to quit -- just quit the AppleScript
        end if

    return 1 -- i.e. poll once per second (maximum)
end tell
```